# Informatica PowerCenter Express 9.6.1: How to Override SQL with Mapping Parameter

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I am trying to use a mapping (user defined) parameter when I override an SQL query (of a relational data object) but I get **"Invalid Parameter Reference"** error!

I get no response from Informatica Community Support, so if anyone has done something similar, please share.

Example SQL Statement:

> SELECT COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, COLUMN_3 FROM MY_TABLE WHERE COLUMN_1 >
>   '$MAPPING_PARAMETER'

Response:
**"Invalid Parameter Reference"**

Answer (score 0):

In informatica Mapping parameters start with"$$"
session parameters start with "$"
Example for an SQL override
Select * FROM TABLE
Where YEAR=**$$Fiscal_Year** ---- For your example change '$MAPPING_PARAMETER' --> '$$MAPPING_PARAMETER'

Comment: It doesn't work with the "$$" in PowerCenter Express.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to Informatica PowerCenter express edition? Informatica PowerCenter express edition currently doesn't support using Mapping parameters in SQL Override.

Comment: Yes, I refer to the Express Edition. Where is it mentioned that it is not supported?